# .net mvc date culture problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, culture

when I have:

```
        var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-fr");
        return date.ToString("dd MMM", cultureInfo);
```

I get back: 01 févr.

When I run the same code but with "en-us", I get back 01 Feb

What I would like is to get 01 fév

Any idea why this is happening (essentially the French culture adds an extra letter and a period) and how to get it to display only 3 month letters?

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to specifically set the `DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames` property.  You can have a look at the MSDN documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames.aspx

Note that, according to the above doc, you also need to set the `DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveName` property as well.